# Mixed signal PCB components placement

Tags: pcb, noise, mixed-signal

I'm designing a PCB that contains digital and analog parts.

I'm thinking of placing the digital parts closest to the source and analog parts farther from the source and after the digital parts.

The picture below illustrates the placement.
`I1` is the current that flows through digital circuitries and contain noise. `I2` is the current through sensitive analog parts.

My intuition says that `I2` will not be affected by the noise of `I1`.

Is that correct?

[image]

Comment: Does your circuit contain ADCs or DACs?

Answer (score 2):

**My intuition says that I2 will not be affected by the noise of I1**

Actually it will, in your circuit any voltage drop (and noise) along the digital lines will affect the analog circuits further down the line.  Try the connection arrangement below for an improved system.  Be sure to use a fair number of by-pass caps at the beginning and ends of the lines (as shown) and at most or all of the supply pins of the chips.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aside from radiated emissions, I2 will transfer noise to I1 depending on the resistance of the supply traces, so you’ll want to keep any shared resistance (I.e. resistance that feeds both I1 and I2 to a minimum, and this includes the source resistance of the power supply.  It’s common practice to add a ferrite bead in series with the supplies; this has the effect of presenting a high impedance at high frequencies.  Some ferrites are specified in this way, e.g. 600 ohms at 100MHz and so you would expect that with a 1 ohm source impedance the conducted noise at 100MHz would be attenuated by a factor of 600.  Decoupling capacitors, as Nedd says, work well with or without ferrites.  Be particularly aware that noise in the ground is just as important as noise in the supply, especially where this is used as a reference voltage.  Fortunately a good ground plane largely eliminates this.